# does this sentence sound right? "Thank you for your consideration and I am glad to hear from you."

Tags: grammar

I got a response from the company that i applied on indeed,
I was going to start my reply with the beginning of this sentence.
Does that sound weird or like not a native? (English is my 2nd language)

"Thank you for your consideration and I am glad to hear from you."

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

That sounds grammatically fine. 
And the following one is to rephrase your sentence with delicacy(I'd go personally); you might take it If you'd like to refine the reply a little:

"I am appreciative of your consideration, and I'd be glad to hear from you".

Answer (score 0):

It is slightly awkward, as after the "for", the reader expects something in the same form as "your consideration", e.g. "Thank you for your consideration and [for] getting back to me." That would be better but both consideration and getting back mean sort of the same thing. Therefore, I would drop the second part entirely and just go with "Thank you for your consideration." Your gladness is implied